# sqlsvr drivers slow response time when connecting to remote azure db

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database

I have set up a virtual machine in windows azure, and a SQL azure DB in the azure portal.

When I connect my web app to the db using the PHP sqlsvr drivers, even though it works, it is painfully slow and retrieving the data. I have found in the past the solution to this problem was to have the database on the same server as the web app.

Is there any way to resolve this problem as I would like to use an Azure DB.

Cheers.

EDIT:

Found this:

[Latency between Azure Web Role and SQL Azure and Application performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574516/latency-between-azure-web-role-and-sql-azure-and-application-performance?rq=1)

Seems to be a common problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your web app hosted in the same region as your Windows Azure SQL Database?

**See:** http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/

> Choose a region. Region determines the geographical location of the
>   server. Regions cannot be easily switched, so choose one that makes
>   sense for this server. Choose a location that is closest to you.
>   Keeping your Windows Azure application and database in the same region
>   saves you on egress bandwidth cost and **data latency**.

Comment: Yep it is, both set up in north europe